# Variable batch sizes don't work with tf.keras.layers.RNN when dropout is used (TF2.0)?

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, dropout

I would like to use the RNN wrapper with multiple LSTM cells with dropout. However, if the batch size changes, I get an error.

When I remove dropout, the code the works just fine, so I believe the issue is that the dropout mask is not being reset between batches.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_dim = 3
output_dim = 3
num_timesteps = 2
neurons = [32,32]

# Model
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_timesteps, input_dim))
cell = [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(n,dropout=.2) for n in neurons]
lstm = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)
lstm_out, hidden_state, cell_state = lstm(input_layer)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)(lstm_out)

mdl = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=input_layer,
    outputs=[hidden_state, cell_state, output]
)

# Run batches of different sizes
batch_1 = np.random.rand(10, num_timesteps, input_dim).astype(np.float32)
h_state, c_state, out = mdl(batch_1) # batch size is 10x2x3

batch_2 = np.random.rand(9, num_timesteps, input_dim).astype(np.float32)
h_state, c_state, out = mdl(batch_2) # batch size is 9x2x3
```

This code gives the error: InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [9,3] vs. [10,3] [Op:Mul] name: model/rnn/mul/

If I take out dropout, the code works. Can I use reset_dropout_mask somehow? It seems it's not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your error with `Tensorflow Version 2.0.0`.

However, there is no error if I upgrade the `Tensorflow Version` either to `2.1` or to `2.2` and run the same code.

Complete working code is shown below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.2

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__) # Printing the Tensorflow Version just to be Sure

input_dim = 3
output_dim = 3
num_timesteps = 2
neurons = [32,32]

# Model
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_timesteps, input_dim))
cell = [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(n,dropout=.2) for n in neurons]
lstm = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)
lstm_out, hidden_state, cell_state = lstm(input_layer)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)(lstm_out)

mdl = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=input_layer,
    outputs=[hidden_state, cell_state, output]
)

# Run batches of different sizes
batch_1 = np.random.rand(10, num_timesteps, input_dim).astype(np.float32)
h_state, c_state, out = mdl(batch_1) # batch size is 10x2x3

batch_2 = np.random.rand(9, num_timesteps, input_dim).astype(np.float32)
h_state, c_state, out = mdl(batch_2) # batch size is 9x2x3
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
2.2.0
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!